# Associated Legendre Equation truncation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

In trying to solve the ALE for the Schrödinger Equation through a power series I have run into a difficulty
$$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dy}{dx}+(A-\frac{m^2}{1-x^2})y=0$$
has as a solution
$$=(1-x^2)^\frac{|m|}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
The recursion relation is then
$$\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+|m|)(n+|m|+1)-A}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$
Now it this series doesn't terminate, for high values of $n$ we have approximately
$$\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}=1$$
So the series becomes as
$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$
But then y only seems to diverge if $|m|=1$, while it converges for larger values. Whta am I missing?

Comment: Are you missing the $a_n$'s in your solution? There are other typos as well in the text.

Comment: Ah, that's my mistake, yes

Comment: I think you can use the Gauss test to determine the convergence of the series.

Comment: Additional information you may be able to use: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283021/legendre-polynomials-laguerre-polynomials-basic-concept/766439#766439