# Proving that the Legendre differential equation has solution of degree $n$ when $p=n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

For $p\geq 0$ the Legendre differential equation is
$$(1-t^2)y''-2ty'+p(p+1)y=0.$$
Two linearly independent solutions that I have found for this diff equation are
$$y_1(t)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{[(p-2n+2)...(p-2)p][(p+1)(p+3)...(p+2n-1)]}{(2n)!}t^{2n}$$and
$$t+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{[(p-2n+1)...(p-3)(p-1)][(p+2)(p+4)...(p+2n)]}{(2n+1)!}t^{2n+1}.$$
How do I show that for $p=m$ (with $m$ an integer) the Legendre diff equation has a polynomial solution of degree $m$?

Comment: You have used the variable $n$ as an index; so your question is rather "if $m$ is an integer, how do I show that for $p=m$" ...... Hint: if $m$ is even, put $m=2n_0-2$, and compute the coeffcient of $t^{2n}$ in the first series for $n\geq n_0+1$

Comment: @Kelenner You were right about the m/n stuff, I'm not sure what to do with the hint. Do you mind making an answer of that?

Comment: It is only a hint, not an answer. The factor $(p-2n+2)...(p-2)$ is zero for what values of $p$ ?

Comment: @Kelenner for p=2?

Comment: $p=2,4,...2n-2$. What is the product if $p=m=2n_0-2$ with $n\geq n_0$ ?

Comment: @Kelenner then the coefficients are zero?

Comment: Yes, you are true; and then the first series is a polynomial.

Comment: @Kelenner but what if p isnt $2n_0-2$?

Comment: If $n$ is even, then one series terminates and gives you a polynomial. If $n$ is odd, the other series terminates and gives you a polynomial. You always get one polynomial solution if $n$ is an integer. The other solution is unbounded near $x = \pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

See my post [About the Legendre differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176357/about-the-legendre-differential-equation/765585#765585) for details of why the equation has a polynomial solution $P_n(x)$ of degree n (the p in your notation).
You can find the other solution there also, for which the expansion does not terminate and which is normally denoted as $Q_n(x)$.

By the way the closed form you included in the question is not really practical in my opinion; better remember Rodrigues' formula
$$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^nn!}[(x^2-1)^n]^{(n)}$$
which clearly is a polynomial of degree n.