# Maclaurin series solution to Legendre equation and general expression for coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, power-series, taylor-expansion, legendre-polynomials

Consider a Maclaurin series solution 
$$y = (1−x^2)y′′ −2xy′ +α(α+1)y=0, −1<x<1.$$

Show that $$a_2 = \frac{-α(α+1)}{6}a_0$$  $$a_3=\frac{−(α−1)(α+2)}{6}a_1$$

and, for all $n≥2$, 
$$a_{n+2} = \frac{n(n+1)−α(α+1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n = \frac{(n−α)(n+α+1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n.$$

Deduce that, if $α = k ∈ \{0,1,2,3,...\},$ then
$$a_{k+2} =a_{k+4} =a_{k+6} =...=0.$$
Hence write down a polynomial solution of Legendre’s equation in the cases $α = 0,1,2,3,4$.
For $α = 3$, write down the first 4 terms in the other series solution of Legendre’s equation and try to find a general expression for the coefficients in this series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to another similar question:
[About the Legendre differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176357/about-the-legendre-differential-equation/765585#765585)
This gives you all the information you need.